# Oracle select with like from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Please assist me for complete this query

```
select *
from table1 a
join table2_n n 
on a.PHONE_NO like '%'|| (select substr(mobile_no,2,9) as mobile_no from table2)
```

table 2 records exists in table1. so i need to get them all from this query

Comment: Can you please explain why you're _not_ just looking for: `select *
from table1 a
join table2_n n 
on a.PHONE_NO like '%'|| substr(n.mobile_no,2,9)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to have a subquery, you can just join the data directly:

```
select a.*
from   table1 a
join   table2 n 
on     a.PHONE_NO like '%'|| substr(mobile_no,2,9);
```

Alternatively, you could write this using an `exists` subquery:

```
select *
from   table1 a
where  exists (select null
               from   table2 n 
               where  a.PHONE_NO like '%'|| substr(mobile_no,2,9));
```

If you have multiple records in table2 matching those in table1, the first query will return you multiple rows from t1 unless you put a `distinct` clause in there.

Comment: Yes, as commented I think this is what the OP is trying to do, but I'm not entirely sure... it's not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use like and subquery, any how you have joined 2 tables with phone_no column, then it'll return all the matching records.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @valex: I feel this is no critique to the author, instead it is a perfect legal answer to "Please assist me for complete this query"

Comment: How can it not be a critique @ralph, it's a question and a statement with nothing to show the OP _how_ they should improve their query.

Answer (score -1):

Use rownum=1 or where condition to return only one row from the inner sub query otherwise it would not work for multiple recods in table2.

Comment: This will only return a random record, which defeats the point of the JOIN right?